# Hibernate Query Hints for JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have been trying to find a definitive resource for all of the hints that can be set through the `Query.setHint(String,Object)` method call in JPA, but I am coming up empty. Anyone know a good reference?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

See ["3.4.1.7. Query hints"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1215).

Comment: above is for 3.5.6 here's link for [Hibernate 4.3.x](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/QueryHints.html)

Comment: Maybe you can add an explanation here. Anytime the link will be dead.