# How to specify hint with jpa and MS SQL

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, locking, playframework

I would like one of my table to have row level locking. I am currently using JPA (hibernate) with play framework.

Is this something that needs to be specified at the DB level or can it be done progammatically?

Comment: Looks like a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015552/hibernate-query-hints-for-jpa

Comment: It does, however this does not seem to answer the question and gives no indication of setting row level locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around I ended up setting the transaction to read_uncommited with the code below.

```
   try{
     Session session = (Session) Report.em().getDelegate();
     Connection connection = session.connection();
     connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
   } catch(SQLException e){
   ...
   }
```

This seems to suit my needs but is not exactly what I was looking for.
Furthermore the session.connection() is deprecated and this might not be a long term solution.